# Getline and parsing data

Tags: c++, file, parsing, getline

My program needs to read from a text file containing no more than 50 player stats. An example of an input would be:

```
Chipper Jones 3B 0.303
Rafael Furcal SS 0.281
Hank Aaron RF 0.305
```

My problem is I can't seem to figure out how to parse the data within each line. I need help figuring out how I'm going to do that, so that the output will look like:

```
Jones, Chipper: 3B (0.303)
Furcal, Rafael: SS (0.281)
Aaron, Hank: RF (0.305)
```

My goal is to create some sort of loop that will run through any available lines, parse the lines, and establish the content of each line to the variables associated with them.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class player
{
private:
    string first, last, position;
    float batave;
    int a;

public:
    void read(string input[50]);
    void print_data(void);

} playerinfo;

void player::print_data(void)
{
    cout << last << ", " << first << ": " << position << " (" << batave << ")" << endl;
}

void player::read(string input[]) // TAKE INFORMATION IN THE FILE AND STORE IN THE CLASS
{
    for (int a = 0; a <= 50; a++);
    {
        // getline(input[0], first, ' ', last, );
    }

}



int main(void)
{
    ifstream infile;
    string filename;
    ofstream outfile;
    string FILE[50];

    cin >> filename;

    infile.open(filename.c_str());

    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "We're sorry! The file specified is unavailable!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The file has been opened!" << endl;

        for (int a = 0; getline(infile, FILE[a]); a++);
        playerinfo.read(FILE);
        playerinfo.print_data();

    }
    printf("\n\n\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

I have to
Prompt the user for the input and output file names. DO NOT hardcode file names into your program.
 Open input file
 Read each player and store them in an array of Player objects
 Keep track of the number of players in the array
 Open an output file
 Write each player from the array into the output file, along with any other output required by the assignment.
 Remember to close your files when done with them

Comment: Do you know about `stringstream`?

Comment: No. This is just supposed to be a basic c++ program of reading a file and then parsing it and sending it back to an outfile.

Answer (score 0):

You have 50 strings for the lines in the input, but only a single `playerinfo`.  It needs to be the other way around--a single string for reading the file, and 50 `playerinfo`s to parse the data into.

Comment: I'm a bit confused still. I have the for loop in main where it just reads every line of the file and afterward sends file to the function where I can then parse it. Is there a way to parse within the function, and is this what you meant?
for (int a = 0; getline(infile, FILE[a]); a++);
  playerinfo[50].read(FILE);

Answer (score 0):

Use stream extraction and insertion operator overloads. For example see the below code and modify according to your needs.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class player {
private:
    string first, last, position;
    float batave;
    int a;

public:
    friend std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & in, player & p) {
        in >> p.first >> p.last >> p.position >> p.batave;
        return in;
    }

    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const player & p) {
        out << p.last << ", " << p.first << ": " << p.position << " (" << p.batave << ")";
        return out;
    }
};

int main() {
    player p;
    while (cin >> p)          // or infile >> p;
        cout << p << endl;    // or outfile << p << endl;
}
```

See a [<kbd>**DEMO**</kbd>](http://ideone.com/Hwj3nW)